# Roles permissions and user roles, proper mapping?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a basic role based access control. Single table for permission (name, description), single table for role (name, description). Question is, how to make proper mapping with the users? So in my mind comes 1 solution:

*role_permission_set* - table

(role_permission_id **PK**, role_id (**many-to-one**), permission_id (**many-to-one**))

*user_role* - table

(user_role_id **PK**, user_id (**many-to-one**), role_permission_id (**many-to-one**))

Two tables for mapping roles permissions and users roles. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this right.

Break it down into two independent many-to-many relationships.  One is between `user` and `role`.  The other is between `role` and `permission`.

Each of those two many-to-many relationships will need a join table similar to what you described.

The only mistake I see in your post is that `user_role` should contain the `role_id` instead of the `role_permission_id`.

```
create table user_role (
  user_role_id int serial primary key,
  user_id int not null references user(user_id),
  role_id int not null references role(role_id),
  constraint uq_user_role unique(user_id, role_id)
);
```

When you want to get a list of `permission` values for a `user`:

```
select distinct p.name
  from user_role ur
  join role_permission rp on rp.role_id = ur.role_id
  join permission p on p.permission_id = rp.permission_id
 where ur.user_id = 123;
```

Comment: theoretically i can omit serial primary key and use just two many to many tables with composite keys and it will be the same?
role_permission (role_id, permission_id) 
user_role (user_id, role_id)
or these serial PK have special meaning?

Comment: There is no special meaning.  You can omit them and use `(role_id, permission_id)`  and `(user_id, role_id)` as the PKs.  I got into the habit of using identity columns over twenty years ago, and I will probably continue using them since there are some use cases where outside tools do not like compound keys.